# How do I set image in Javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Krajee bootstrap file upload plugin found [here](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#events)

and I'm calling the event 'fileLoaded' when the image is finished uploading.
I have an image element on the page I want to set to the image I justuploaded.

Below I want to pass file.src to image.src, but file.src is undefined. file only has name, size and type. And the name is just the name of the image I uploaded - test.jpg

```
 $('#input-20').on('fileloaded', function (event, file, previewId, index, reader) {
         console.log("fileloaded");

         var image = document.getElementById("displayImage");
         image.src = file.src;


});
```

Comment: `$('#input-20')` instead of `('#input-20')`.

Comment: I see you commented out `$("#pic1").attr("src", searchPic.src);` In jQuery using the `$(<selector>).attr('src', <source>)` method does work so you probably have a problem elsewhere

Comment: It looks like I can use 'reader' to read the data from the file, but not sure how to do that or how to set it afterwards to image.src

Comment: It seems like `file` is an `object` with the properties `name`, `size` and `type` attached to it. As the library you are using does not attach `src` parameter  to the object properties you have to use it's `name` property and concatenate that with the folder `path` where the images are being stored on the server.

Comment: Something like `var targetImageSrc = document.domain + '/your_upload_directory/' + file.name;` then later you can do `$('#pic1').attr('src', targetImageSrc);`

Comment: I did misunderstand what you are doing but the file still has to come from somewhere, even if you aren't uploading to the server. Think about what a `src` attribute it is. It stands for `source` meaning an absolute or relative `path` on the server from which the browser will render content. In this case you will need to load it from a temp file location